# How to make matplotlib plots in jupyter notebook with latex use non-serif fonts?

Tags: matplotlib, latex, jupyter-notebook

I want to plot with latex in a jupyter notebook with non-serif fonts.

I installed some packages:

```
sudo apt install font-manager texlive-latex-base texlive-latex-extra texlive-math-extra dvipng
```

I cleared the matplotlib cache:

```
rm ~/.cache/matplotlib -rf
```

I am using this code:

```
%pylab inline
rcParams['text.usetex'] = True
rcParams['text.latex.unicode'] = True
rcParams['text.latex.preamble'] = [r'\usepackage{amsmath}']
plot(range(10))
title('Test')
xlabel('Test')
```

Though the plot has serif ticks-labels:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

After activating latex with the `rc` function, using the following latex preamble seems to be all that is necessary to get the desired result. This works, but I don't know why. I guess `%pylab inline` does the magic? You don't even have to tell `matplotlib` to use sans-serif like that. `\mathrm` makes the formula in the title non-italic.

```
%pylab inline
figure(dpi=100)
rc('text', usetex=True)
rcParams['text.latex.preamble'] = [r'\usepackage[cm]{sfmath}']
plot(np.arange(10)/10)
xlabel(r'Time $i_{k} [s]$', size=12)
title('$\mathrm{\sum_{i} T_i}$')
```

[image]

Comment: The magic happens because of the preamble `\usepackage[cm]{sfmath}`, which loads the sans serif package in latex and hence causes math mode (i.e. things between $ signs) to be rendered in this font.

Comment: The fonts look quite squeezend is there a better font?

Comment: I guess your options are essentially listed [here](http://dtrx.de/od/tex/sfmath.html). Else, is there any reason to actually use latex in your figure? Mostly matplotlib can handle mathtext quite well itself.

Comment: This is just an example figure. Though without latex matplotlib does not handle formulas very well. Calling tight_layout() for example doesn't do a good job with it. Even with this example, try it without latex and the title will reach into the figure.

Comment: Ah, good point. This is an issue with the tight_layout manager. I [brought it up on the issue tracker](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/11468), but it will for sure not be fixed soon.